# regular triangulations of the product of two simplices

Tags: co.combinatorics, convex-polytopes, triangulations

Is description of all regular triangluations of $\Delta^n\times \Delta^k$ known? (Regular triangulations are those which correspond to vertices of Gelfand--Kapranov--Zelevinsky secondary polytope, or, equivalently, those which correspond to domains of linearity of a convex function.) Estimates of the number of triangulations is also of interest.

Comment: Perhaps Francisco Santos' paper, "The Cayley trick and triangulations of products of simplices," is relevant. ([arXiv abstract](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0312069).) He computes the exact number of triangulations of $\Delta^2 \times \Delta^k$ up to $k \le 15$, and includes some discussion of $\Delta^3 \times \Delta^3$.

Comment: They should be the same as combinatorial types of tropical hyperplane arrangements. See http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0605598.pdf

Comment: I would say no "combinatorial" description that distinguishes regular from non-regular triangulations of $\Delta^n\times \Delta^k$ is known. For example, my paper cited by Jo O'Rourke above contains a nice description and a counting algorithm for triangulations of $\Delta^2\times \Delta^k$, but none of them distinguish the regular from the non-regular.

In terms of asymptotics, in the same paper I show that the number of regular triangulations of $\Delta^n\times \Delta^k$ is less than $\left(\frac{e}{2}kn\right)^{n(n-1)(k-1)}$.